# Socket server displaying wrong IP

Tags: python, sockets, ip

Im making a chat app with sockets and Im having a small issue. Im running the server off my laptop and then I connect to the server from a client running inside of a virtual machine on the same laptop.

chat_server.py

```
import socket
import subprocess
import platform
from _thread import *

def get_local_ip():
    system_platform = platform.system().lower()

    try:
        if system_platform == 'darwin':
            # macOS
            result = subprocess.run(["ifconfig", "en0"], capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
            local_ip = [line.split()[1] for line in result.stdout.splitlines() if "inet " in line][0]
        elif system_platform == 'linux':
            # Linux
            result = subprocess.run(["ifconfig"], capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
            # Find the first non-loopback IPv4 address
            local_ip = next((line.split()[1] for line in result.stdout.splitlines() if "inet " in line and "127.0.0.1" not in line), None)
        elif system_platform == 'windows':
            # Windows
            result = subprocess.run(["ipconfig"], capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
            local_ip = [line.split(":")[1].strip() for line in result.stdout.splitlines() if "IPv4 Address" in line][0]
        else:
            print("Unsupported operating system")
            return None

        if local_ip is None:
            raise Exception("Failed to retrieve a valid local IP address.")

        return local_ip
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error running command: {e}")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting local IP: {e}")
        return None


def start_server():
    host_ip = get_local_ip()
    port_number = int(input("Enter the port number: "))

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    server_socket.bind((host_ip, port_number))
    server_socket.listen(100)
    print(f"{host_ip} listening on port {port_number}")
    client_list = []

    def handle_client(client_conn, client_address):
        client_conn.send("Connection successful. You can now start chatting!".encode('utf-8'))

        while True:
            try:
                message = client_conn.recv(2048)
                if message:
                    print(f"{client_address[0]}: {message.decode('utf-8')}")
                    broadcast_message = f"{message.decode('utf-8')}"
                    broadcast(broadcast_message, client_conn)
                else:
                    remove_client(client_conn)
            except:
                continue

    def broadcast(message, sender_connection):
        for client_socket in client_list:
            if client_socket != sender_connection:
                try:
                    client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
                except:
                    client_socket.close()
                    remove_client(client_socket)

    def remove_client(client_connection):
        if client_connection in client_list:
            client_list.remove(client_connection)

    while True:
        client_conn, client_addr = server_socket.accept()
        client_list.append(client_conn)
        print(f"{client_addr[0]} connected")
        start_new_thread(handle_client, (client_conn, client_addr))

    client_conn.close()
    server_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()
```

chat_client.py

```
import socket
import select
import sys

def start_client():
    server_ip = input("Enter the server IP address: ")
    server_port = int(input("Enter the server port: "))

    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    client_socket.connect((server_ip, server_port))

    username = input("Enter your username: ")

    while True:
        active_sockets = [sys.stdin, client_socket]

        readable_sockets, _, _ = select.select(active_sockets, [], [])

        for current_socket in readable_sockets:
            if current_socket == client_socket:
                message = current_socket.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
                print(message)
            else:
                message = sys.stdin.readline()
                client_socket.send(f"{username}: {message}".encode('utf-8'))

    client_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_client()
```

Whenever a connection is made to the server from a client, the server is supposed to display the IP of the client that has connected, but it keeps displaying the IP of the server.

example

```
Enter the port number: 5000
10.180.186.206 listening on port 5000
10.180.186.206 connected
```

Ive run ifconfig on the virtual machine to get its IP, and as far as im concerned the server should be showing this when the client connects:

```
Enter the port number: 5000
10.180.186.206 listening on port 5000
10.211.55.7 connected
```

How can I make the the IP address of the connected client be displayed instead of the servers IP.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the output you are seeing is from the client running on the VM? After all, your server is designed to handle multiple clients and it would make sense for you to start another client to test the chat features, perhaps including starting one on the same machine as the server is running on.

Comment: Yeah I just did a test using a client from my VM and another client from the same machine the server is running on. Both times when connected, it shows the same IP, the servers IP.